# How to construct a column table using forelse and if in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

this my source code and I apologize for the messy layout of my code syntax, i want to fill the td like this
[image]

```html
<tbody>
    @forelse ($kaders as $kader)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $kader->username }}</td>
            @if($kader->status_user == '1')
                <td>Admin</td>
            @elseif($kader->status_user == '0')
                <td>Ibu / Guest</td>
            @endif
            @forelse ($surveillances as $surveillance)
                @if($kader->username == $surveillance->nik_ortu)
                    @if($surveillance->status == '1')
                        <td>Aktif</td>
                    @elseif($surveillance->status == '0')
                        <td>NonAKtif</td>
                    @endif
                @endif
                <!-- <td>admin</td> -->
            @empty
                <td>admin</td>
            @endforelse
            <td class="text-center">
                <form onsubmit="return confirm('Apakah Anda Yakin ?');" action="{{ route('kader.destroy', $kader->id) }}" method="POST">
                    @method('DELETE')
                    @csrf
                    <a href="{{ route('kader.edit', $kader->id) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
                        <i class="far fa-edit"></i> EDIT
                    </a>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">
                        <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i> HAPUS
                    </button>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    @empty
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            Data Kader belum Tersedia.
        </div>
    @endforelse
</tbody>
```

how can i construct like the pic above ? thank you for advice

Comment: That's not how the ``@empty`` tag works. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#if-statements

Comment: Please share your Array what data return in array?

Comment: yeah i think this just how i use the if statement inside table cell structure @OMiShah

Comment: This is too long and difficult to explain here but atleast i found my answer.. @HarshPatel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<tbody>
    @forelse ($kaders as $kader)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $kader->username }}</td>
        <td>
        @if($kader->status_user == '1')
        Admin
        @elseif($kader->status_user == '0')
        Ibu / Guest
        @endif
        </td>
        <td>
        @forelse ($surveillances as $surveillance)
            @if($kader->username == $surveillance->nik_ortu)
                @if($surveillance->status == '1')
                Aktif
                @elseif($surveillance->status == '0')
                NonAKtif
                @endif
            @endif
        @empty
        admin
        @endforelse
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <form onsubmit="return confirm('Apakah Anda Yakin ?');" action="{{ route('kader.destroy', $kader->id) }}" method="POST">
                <a href="{{ route('kader.edit', $kader->id) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><i class="far fa-edit"></i> EDIT</a>
                @csrf
                @method('DELETE')
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i> HAPUS</button>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
    @empty
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            Data Kader belum Tersedia.
        </div>
    @endforelse
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the table cell outside the if-then block so if there's nothing an empty cell will be created instead of no cell. Change this:

```
@if($kader->status_user == '1')
    <td>Admin</td>
@elseif($kader->status_user == '0')
    <td>Ibu / Guest</td>
@endif
@forelse ($surveillances as $surveillance)
    @if($kader->username == $surveillance->nik_ortu)
        @if($surveillance->status == '1')
        <td>Aktif</td>
        @elseif($surveillance->status == '0')
        <td>NonAKtif</td>
        @endif
    @endif
        <!-- <td>admin</td> -->
    @empty
        <td>admin</td>
@endforelse
```

to this:

```
<td>
    @if($kader->status_user == '1')
        Admin
    @elseif($kader->status_user == '0')
        Ibu / Guest
    @endif
</td>
<td>
    @forelse ($surveillances as $surveillance)
        @if($kader->username == $surveillance->nik_ortu)
            @if($surveillance->status == '1')
                Aktif
            @elseif($surveillance->status == '0')
                NonAKtif
            @endif
        @endif
            <!-- <td>admin</td> -->
    @empty
        admin
    @endforelse
</td>
```

Comment: wait, i will try this